# Stuck in query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum, pivot

I have a table as:

[image]

My expected output is(10,20,30 are deptno):

[image]

So I tried like this:

```
select job,case 
                when deptno=10 then sum(sal) else null
                end dept_10_data
           ,case 
                when deptno=20 then sum(sal) else null
                end dept_20_data ,
              case 
                when deptno=30 then sum(sal) else null
                end dept_30_data       
 from ot.employee group by job;
```

But I am getting error as:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

How can I get this output?

Comment: Never add data as an image....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to put the `case` expression *inside* an aggregate function. Here, you want to use `sum()`.

```
select 
    job,
    sum(case when deptno = 10 then sal end) dept_10_data,
    sum(case when deptno = 20 then sal end) dept_20_data,
    sum(case when deptno = 30 then sal end) dept_30_data
from ot.employee 
group by job;
```

Comment: @GMB you don't need to add in the `else 0` bit; `SUM` ignores NULL values.

Comment: @Boneist: yes you are correct, I just [tested that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4bfea78739183e6d0542fa9ed5e72c4) and found out.

Answer (score 2):

You have your conditional aggregation around the wrong way. You should apply the condition to the data first, then aggregate, e.g.:

```
SELECT job,
       SUM(case when deptno = 10 then sal end) dept_10_data,
       ...
FROM   ot.employee
GROUP BY job;
```

N.B. I haven't included a default value if the deptno is not the specified value, since most aggregate functions (including `SUM`) ignore NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

You met with the error due to the usage of direct columns in `select` clause (without `aggregate` function) without mentioning them in `group by` clause. (As mentioned in both the answers).

But you can also use `PIVOT` for same output as following:

```
Select * from
(Select job, deptno, sal from ot.employee)
Pivot
(Sum(sal) for deptno in (10,20,30))
```

Cheers!!